# Change background color of "th" on change to the immediately next td

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I want to change the color of a 'th' element after I make a change to the 'input' elem in the 'td' element just beside it.

Here is the jQuery script I used.

```
$('#phoneNo').change(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("th").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
```

HTML code

```
<tr>
    <th>PhoneNo</th>
    <td><input type="text" id="phoneNo"/></td>
    <th>EmailId</th>
    <td><input type="text" id="emailId"/></td>

</tr>
```

It behaves like I can expect - It changes the background color of all 'th' elements(both PhoneNo and EmailId in the code) in the row. But what I want is to change the color of only one 'th'-the one just preceding the corresponding 'td'(only PhoneNo)

Comment: Oh, I could have used 'id' on each 'th' elems. Dumb of me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#phoneNo').change(function () {
    $(this).parent().prev("th").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Note that since `.prev()` is looking for previous siblings, you need to find first the td element

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#phoneNo').change(function () {
    $(this).parent().prev('th').css("background-color","yellow");
});​
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/zSjMh/1/